# Visual Basic .Net encoding

Tags: vb.net

Here's my current code:

```
Dim webber As New Net.WebClient

**webber.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8**

htmlsource = webber.DownloadString(URL)
```

How do I change that part so that I can use 949, the code for Korean encode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
webber.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(949)
```

(I'm surprised `WebClient` doesn't use the headers in the response to determine which encoding to use. It's possible that it does, and that the encoding specified here is only used if the response doesn't specify anything, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

Hello try this for korean

```
webber.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(949);

949 is a Korean  code page
```

Also refer 
[MS Kink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)